# Построчная запись в файл из List (Java)

Tags: java

В чём проблема : не знаю как сохранить данные из List в файл .txt
Т.е. данные он сохраняет правильно,я могу обратиться к элементам List,они выводятся на экран.Но вот как всё это дело сохранить в текстовый файл?

```
public static void parser() throws IOException {

    List<Neews> news = new ArrayList<>();
    Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://").get();
    Elements trElements = doc.getElementsByAttributeValue("class", "con_title");

    trElements.forEach(trElement -> {
        Elements elementsByClass = trElement.getElementsByClass("con_title");
        String name = elementsByClass.get(0).text();
        news.add(new Neews(name));
    });
 news.forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

Comment: я вот думаю,что если просто List конвертировать в обычный массив и сохранить обычным Writer'ом?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Конструктор класса `Neews` я не знаю, допустим в него нужно передавать имя и фамилию. Также допустим, что в этом классе есть методы геттеры `getName()` для получения имени и `getFamily()` для получения фамилии

```
List<Neews> list = new ArrayList<>();

//здесь, заместо комментария, вы заполняете ArrayList или как там у вас, вообщем после этого он у вас содержит данные

FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("output.txt");
for(Neews news : list {
String name = news.getName();
String family = news.getFamily();
writer.write(name + " " + family + System.getProperty("line.separator"));
}
writer.close();
```

В итоге файл `output.txt` будет содержать имена и фамилии, разделенные пробелами. Причём пары ФИ будут разделены переводом на следующую строку

Comment: Прекрасно! Сейчас посмотрю,а в классе Neews там одно поле - name.
Простите,что не скинул его) что-то не подумал)

Comment: `getName()` есть?

Comment: Если только одно поле, то зачем вам вообще класс? Вы можете использовать обычный `ArrayList`

Comment: это не важно) в общем на следующую строку он не переносит,не понимаю почему так выходит(

Comment: Обновил ответ. Посмотрите

Comment: вот теперь замечательно) благодарю)

Comment: Не выполняйте двойную работу проходя по листу через `for` с индексом и используя `get()`. Достаточно использовать проход итератором: `for(Neews neews: list)`

Comment: Ой. Я хотел написать в виде `for-each`, но не понял как, сейчас поправлю

Answer (score 4):

Записать в файл построчно, можно вот так:

```
List<String> lines = Arrays.asList("hello", "world");
Files.write(Paths.get("demo.txt"), lines, StandardOpenOption.CREATE);
```

Comment: Это что за класс такой? `Files`

Comment: @СергейГрушин [java.nio.file.Files](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html).

Comment: Не заглядывал в этот пакет, `java.nio`. Видимо активно его используют

Answer (score 0):

Добавье в конце `"\n"` - знак переноса, например:

```
writer.write(name + " " + family + System.getProperty("line.separator") + "\n")
```

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).